# Can online node.js server store minimal client connection data?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, server, amazon-fire-tv

so I'm new to node.js, and just made a node.js server for a chess game.  It seems to work, but I have some questions about the structure.

Right now, I just have the server maintain an array of chess-table-data, each of which only stores a table# and the users' IP addresses.

Is this ok?

Or, does all data storage have to be done in an actual database?

I'm new to this stuff.  I remember reading that node.js can distribute its data across different servers, so that maybe some of my data wont be avail on all servers?  Does this affect my situation?  I'm not expecting heavy amounts of traffic for this app.

Comment: For a simple PoC, this is probably fine. If you want to be able to turn off/on the server without losing data, however, you'll want to look into a more permanent datastore. Node works really well with MongoDB using the mongoose or monk plugins, but honestly you could use anything you're comfortable with.

Comment: i suggest redis for fault-tolerance and thread pooling. a DB will work too, but is overkill for transient data

Comment: thanks.  does the node data go across multiple servers by default?  or would i have to specify node to do that?  because if people are trying to connect, yet are accessing different servers, that might not work

Comment: If you service goes down for maintenance/upgrades/etc, then players will loose there data, so I would persist in a local database. There are a number of small foot-print databases that can help persist data--redis, couchdb, pouchdb, leveldb, sqlite3, etc.  Level and pouch are probably the easiest to work with.  [Here](https://github.com/darrylwest/simple-node-db) is a simple example.